# fotorama.js is not working in dynamically generated page content using ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, image-gallery, dynamic-data, fotorama

> Fotorama

is not working in dynamically generated page content using Ajax in

> Php

. how to add photo gallery in dynamic page content